# How to find a $\delta>0$ from information in a graph so that $0<|x-2|<\delta$ implies $|\frac1x-0.5|<0.2$?

Tags: calculus, epsilon-delta

Use the graph below to find a $\delta \gt 0$ such that 
$$
0 \lt \lvert x -2 \rvert \lt \delta \Rightarrow \lvert \frac {1}{x}-0.5\rvert \lt 0.2 $$

[image: y=1/x]

Provided answer is $\delta = \frac {4}{7}$

---

What I have done:

Given $\varepsilon \gt 0, \varepsilon = 0.2$, for $0 \lt \lvert x -2 \rvert \lt \delta \Rightarrow \lvert \frac {1}{x}-0.5\rvert \lt \varepsilon $

$\lvert x-2 \rvert \\= \lvert (x)(1- \frac{2}{x}) \rvert \\= \lvert (-2x)(\frac{1}{x}-0.5) \rvert$

Since $\lvert x-2 \rvert \lt \delta$ and $\lvert \frac {1}{x}-0.5 \rvert \lt 0.2$

$0.2\lvert -2x \rvert \lt \delta$

$\lvert 2x \rvert \lt 5\delta$

$-5\delta \lt 2x \lt 5\delta$

Comment: @mfl Whoops. Edited the title.

Comment: In your question, should it be *assumed* that $\epsilon=.2$?

Comment: @Jack My bad. Instead of $\varepsilon$, it should be 0.2

Comment: I have edited the title of your post since your question is not about a proof of $\lim_{x\to 2}\frac{1}{x}=\frac{1}{2}$ *per se*.

Comment: The question says "Use the graph", and you should really do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The questions says "use the graph ...". We are looking for a value $\delta$ such that if $2-\delta<x<2+\delta$ then the graph of the function is between $0.3$ and $0.7.$ It is clear that if $$\dfrac{1}{0.7}<x<\dfrac{1}{0.3}$$ then the graph satisfies the conditions. Now $\delta$ is given by the minimum distance from $2$ to $\frac{10}{7}$ and $\frac{10}{3}.$ Since

$$\left|2-\dfrac{10}{7}\right|=\dfrac 47<\dfrac 43=\left|2-\dfrac{10}{3}\right|$$

we get that $\delta =\dfrac 47.$

Comment: Sorry but I think there may be a mistake. Isn't $\frac {10}{7}-2 = -\frac {4}{7}$

Comment: @KevinKoh Yes. Sure. Thank you for pointing it. I will fix it in a moment.

Comment: Could you further elaborate on this?


_Now $\delta$ is given by the minimum distance from $2$ to $\frac {10}{7}$ and $\frac {10}{3}$. 
Since

$\lvert 2− \frac{10}{7} \rvert=\frac{4}{7} \lt \frac {4}{3} = \lvert 2− \frac{10}{3} \rvert$

We get that  $\delta=\frac{4}{7}$._

Comment: If you look at the graph there are two important points: $10/7$ where the function takes the value $0.7$ and $10/3$ where the function takes the value $0.3.$ Since you want to have the graph between those values by a condition on $|x-2|$ you have to choose the most restrictive condition. That is, the minimum distance to $2.$

Answer (score 0):

$$|\frac {1}{x}-0,5|=|\frac {x-2}{\color {green}{2}x}|$$

as we are near $2$, we can assume that

$|x-2| <\color {red}{1}$ or $1<x <3$.

thus
$$|\frac {1}{x}-0,5|<\frac {|x-2|}{\color {green}{2}} $$

hence, to get $$|\frac{1}{x}-0,5|<\epsilon$$

we just need to have

$|x-2|<\color {red}{1}$ and $|x-2|<\color {green}{2}\epsilon $.

So we will take
$$\delta=\min (\color {red}{1},\color {green}{2}\epsilon) $$

Answer (score 0):

We will prove the stronger statement

> For every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that, if 
>   $|x-2| < \delta$, then $\left| \dfrac 1x - \dfrac 12 \right| < \epsilon$

Let $\delta = \min\{ 1, \epsilon\}$.

Then $0 < \delta < 1$. It follows that $2-1 < 2 - \delta$ and $2 + \delta < 2+1$.

\begin{align}
   |x-2| < \delta 
   &\implies 2-\delta < x < 2 + \delta \\
   &\implies 1 < x < 3 \\
   &\implies \frac 13 < \frac 1x < 1 \\
      &\implies \frac 16 < \frac{1}{2x} < \frac 12
\end{align}
It follow that

\begin{align}
   \left| \dfrac 1x - \dfrac 12 \right|
   &= \left| \dfrac 12 - \dfrac 1x \right| \\
   &= \dfrac{1}{2x}|x - 2| \\
   &< \dfrac 12|x - 2| \\
   &< \dfrac 12 \delta \\
   &< \dfrac 12 \epsilon \\
   &< \epsilon
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Such exercise suggests students to think about the geometric meaning of the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ proof instead of blind algebraic manipulations.

> Find a $\delta \gt 0$ such that $0 \lt \lvert x -2 \rvert \lt \delta \Rightarrow \lvert \frac {1}{x}-0.5\rvert \lt 0.2 $

Note that $0<|x-2|<\delta$ means
$$
x\in(2-\delta,2+\delta)\quad\hbox{and }\ \ \ x\neq 2,
$$
which means that $x$ falls in the interval $(2-\delta,2+\delta)$ (except the center of the interval: $2$).

On the other hand,
$\lvert \frac {1}{x}-0.5\rvert \lt 0.2$ means
$$
\frac1x\in(0.5-0.2,0.5+0.2)=(0.3,0.7). 
$$
(Can you see that how this coincides with the interval on the $y$-axis of the graph?)

Now look at the graph, which suggests (make sure that you understand this!) that **if** $x\in(\frac{1}{0.7},\frac{1}{0.3})$, then 
$$
\frac{1}{x}\in(0.3,0.7)\tag{*}
$$
But wait, we are looking for $(2-\delta,2+\delta)$ so that if $x\in (2-\delta,2+\delta)$ then (*) is true. ($x\neq 2$ is really irrelevant.) Now observe that if we can make 
$$
(2-\delta,2+\delta)\subset (\frac{1}{0.7},\frac{1}{0.3})
$$
then we are done. Can you see how to go on?